# VUE - load component only if slot exist

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I would like to load a component into a slot only if the slot exists (because I don't want to waste resources creating and mounting the component).

So I did it like that:

Test.vue

```
<slot :load="true" name="slotNo1"/
```

Wrapper.vue

```
<template slot="slotNo1" slot-scope="{ load }"> <Test v-if="load" /> </template>
```

But I wonder if there is an easier way without having to create the "load" variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this

```js
Vue.component('Custom', {
    template: `
    <div>
    <span>always displayed</span>
    <strong v-if="hasSlotData">
        displayed only when slot passed: <slot></slot>
    </strong>
  </div>
    `,
  computed: {
    hasSlotData() {
        return this.$slots.default;
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
    el: '#root'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="root">
  <custom></custom>
  <custom>content</custom>
</div>
```

If you wanna control parent, this may help you https://michaelnthiessen.com/advanced-vue-controlling-parent-slots

Comment: it is a reverse relationship. In the "parent" I want to know if the component it includes has slots (if yes then load components into etc. ).

Comment: @user88831 Updated the answer with an link